# How to remove the thumb of UISlider in iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uislider

I have two UISliders in the same view.My requirement is,when user change the value of 1st slider,the 2nd slider value should be change according to it.So,in 2nd slider I want to invisible its thumb.Although I have clear the color of its thumb,It is visible to the user.How can I solve it ?

Comment: Why don't you use progress bar instead of slider ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply set the image for the thumb to be nil

```
UIImage *empty = [UIImage new];
[theSlider setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage alloc] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[theSlider setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage alloc] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 8):

Easy One :

```
[_slider setThumbImage:[UIImage new] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply go to xib select slider -->  Utilities --> show attributes Inspectors --> Thumb Tint Colour (Clear Thumb tint colour)

[image]

Comment: That hides the thumb but there seems to be an offset at its beginning and end (for example, it seems to be loaded at 5% when it's actually 0% and it seems to be at 95% when it's actually 100%). The `UIImage()` solution worked better unfortunately.